# How to store user input if it was something like a sentence? Or if it was someones name?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Similar to my old question. Is there a way I can store what the user inputs into an array so I can call it via stringName[1] or stringName[2]? 
I am not well versed in java split. 
 for example, if I had

```
System.out.println ("A sentence or your full name please" );
for (int j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++){
array[j]= sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(array[0]);
```

this only prints out the first name

if the user inputs "John Will Smith" and later i want to print out

```
System.out.println (+firstName);
System.out.println (+middleName);
System.out.println (+lastName);
```

how do i go about individually updating the array or split it in a way I can grab what the user inputted?

Answer (score 0):

Use of a `for` loop seems useless here. Read the string as a line and then split it by white space. Check the below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("A sentence or your full name please");
    String fullName = scanner.nextLine(); //Read the full name
    String[] nameArray = fullName.split("\\s+"); //Split the full name by white spaces and insert it to array
    for (String name : nameArray) { //Print names in array
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error

Comment: @River Can you please show me the error?